# Centering an element relative to its sibling

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

I am coding in ReactJS.
I have a bottom NavBar and contents of my homepage. I want the content of my homepage to be centered relative to the bottom navigation bar.
I fail to realize how to achieve that for two siblings.

```js
const HomeLogo = () => {
  return (
    <Container className="homeLogo">
      <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <Image src={logo}/>
      </Row> 
    </Container>
  );
};
```

```js
export const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <HomeLogo />
      <NavBar />
    </>
  );
};
```

This is my CSS:

```css
.homeLogo {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I want the top and bottom of the logo to be of equal length. Please see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryGGX.png)

Here is the Sandbox link for the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/long-wood-4tzin?file=/src/components/Home.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some changes in the HTML & CSS (in the sandbox code):

In the **home.js** wrap any three  in a div:

```
<div className="parent">
  <div className="content">
  <HomeContent />
  <HomeContent />
  <HomeContent />
  </div>
  <NavBar />
</div>
```

In the **NavBar.js**, add this class:

```
  <Navbar className="nav" bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed="bottom">
```

Finally, in the **app.css**:

```
.parent {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav{
  height: 10%;
}

.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hope you solve this problem please follow below code; I am share sandbox code link
[Sandbox Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-worker-dzwg8) you can see live demo

```js
import Navbar from "./Navbar/Navbar";
import HomeLogo from "./HomeLogo/HomeLogo";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <HomeLogo />
      <Navbar />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;

const HomeLogo = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="home-content">Home Logo Here</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default HomeLogo;

const Navbar = () => {
  return <div className="navbar">Bottom Navbar</div>;
};
export default Navbar;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.home-content {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 222;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am using React-Bootstrap dependency. And the modifications do not apply to React-Bootstrap.

Comment: here is the sandbox link for the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/long-wood-4tzin?file=/src/components/Home.js

Comment: ok, i will try to solve. thanks

Comment: I hope you have been waiting for such a solution. i am update your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/dysbf.

Comment: My goal is to center the content of the page vertically, also. So, if I have one image only, then that image must be centered both vertically and horizontally in the space available above the bottom navigation bar.

Comment: Please check the other answer. It correctly addresses the question. Thank you for your replies, though.